# how to request addDelegates ? 415 error

Tags: php, google-admin-sdk

may I need to access to the emailsettings api with POST action in php.

But i always get this error : 
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 415 Unsupported Media Type

Here is my code:

```
      public function addDelegates($account,$delegates,$domain,$tokken) {

foreach ($delegates as $key => $value) {
                    sleep(5);
      $url = "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/".$domain."/".$account."/delegation";
$requestXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                            <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006">
                                <apps:property name="address" value="' . $value . '" />
                            </atom:entry>';
$requestHeaders = array(
    'Content-type: application/xml+atom',
    'Accept: application/xml+atom',
    sprintf('Content-Length: %d', strlen($requestXML))
);

$context = stream_context_create(
                array(
                    'http' => array(
                        'method'  => 'POST',
                        'header'  => implode("\r\n", $requestHeaders),
                        'content' => $requestXML,
                    )
                )
            );
$responseXML = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
  }
```

I saw that this error means that i may send wrong content type. But i tried application/json, application/xml, text/xml etc..

Nothing is precised about what data we have to send in emailSettings api doc :/

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I think content type in your posted code is not correct. change content-type to "application/atom+xml" instead of application/xml+atom. This should resolve your 415 error.

Comment: Thank you ! It was just this .. And i spent one long day working on it and finally accept to share my issue here.
What a luck you've been there to answer.

Comment: Glad that your issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think content type in your posted code is not correct. change content-type to "application/atom+xml" instead of application/xml+atom. This should resolve your 415 error.